# kCCAlignmentError - using kCCAlgorithm3DES Algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, tripledes

I have been facing this Alignment, even though i have encoded my key to base64. I want to encrypt my data without using any padding also i would like to share my input as well :

input = @"136bc704-39dc-4bd7-9b28-a03816dcab6e|chrome|verifyCredential|1459840622290";

key = @"136bc704-39dc-4bd7-9b28-a03816dcab6e";

```
+ (NSData *)tripleDesEncryptString:(NSString *)input
                           key:(NSString *)key
                         error:(NSError **)error
{
      NSParameterAssert(input);
      NSParameterAssert(key);
      NSData *inputData = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSData *keyData1 = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSString *base64Encoded = [keyData1 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
      NSLog(@"Encoded: %@", base64Encoded);


       NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Encoded options:0];




      size_t outLength;

      NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length  +  kCCBlockSize3DES)];

      CCCryptorStatus
      result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, //
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES, //
                       kCCOptionECBMode, //
                       keyData.bytes, //
                       keyData.length, //
                       nil,// iv
                       inputData.bytes, //
                       inputData.length, //  ,
                       outputData.mutableBytes, //
                       outputData.length, //
                       &outLength); //

      if (result != kCCSuccess) {
          if (error != NULL) {
              *error = [NSError       errorWithDomain:@"com.your_domain.your_project_name.your_class_name."
                                           code:result
                                       userInfo:nil];
          }
          return nil;
      }
      [outputData setLength:outLength];
      return outputData;
}
```

Comment: Even if you can magically get this to work, you're a long way off of being secure. First learn about cryptography *then implement*. Other code may be OK if it just runs. With cryptographic that doesn't say anything at all; you need your code to be secure rather than just functional.

Comment: I think i have issue in making key from string.

Comment: The cryptographically right answer is to use a KDF. Alternatively, as a step up, you could take the right amount of leftmost bytes of a cryptographically secure hash. But with ECB mode and a lot of encoding issues, there will be other issues to deal with.